# Blocking charts from removing

Tags: excel, vba

I have a chart that I want user not to delete. Yet I'd like to give him option to move or resize it if he wants to, so I think, that option `locked` in properties is not appropriate here (I use `secure worksheet` too).

Is there any possibility here to make code that works when user clicks `Del` on the keyboard, then some `msgBox` with information with error, that this chart is not deletable appears and then discard this action of removing?

Comment: There is some information here that may relevent to your question: https://peltiertech.com/Excel/ChartsHowTo/ChartProtection.html You will also have to consider the possibility of the chart being removed through cutting. A possible solution would be to have a vba script that checks the charts exist and if any are missing to recreate them.

Answer (score 1):

**It is impossible to prevent `Chart` deletion, while simultaneously enabling it to be moved**

There are two following options, which *sorta* achieve what you want:

1. **Enable Sheet Protection** (`Review -> Protect Sheet`) which will achieve the following:

   - prevent the Chart from being deleted
   - unfortunately also prevent chart from being moved
2. **Use `Application.OnKey` to detect press of <kbd>Delete</kbd>**

   ```
   Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
       Application.OnKey "{DELETE}", "PreventDeletion"
   End Sub

   Private Sub PreventDeletion()
       MsgBox ("Deletion not allowed in this worksheet")
   End Sub
   ```

   - this allows the chart to be moved
   - unfortunately only creates an illusion of delete protection. If user uses mouse2 and selects the delete option, it will still be available to him. This only interrupts pressing the <kbd>Delete</kbd>
   - also this renders <kbd>Delete</kbd> obsolete for entire Sheet, which can be annoying (for the users)

Neither option is ideal, though personally I prefer the first one, as preventing usage of <kbd>Delete</kbd> altogether is bound to annoy your users.